# HD Photo source compile on ARM?

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, arm, porting

I've downloaded [HD Photo Device Porting Kit 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=285eeffd-d86c-48c3-ab93-3abd5ee7f1ce) and successfully compiled and executed it on x86 PC.

I want to port the image viewer program to ARM-based Windows Mobile Smartphone, but there is some missing ARM code.

First, no "/image/x86/x86.h" equivalent header file for ARM. But the file is very simple, so I copied and renamed it to "arm.h" and successfully compiled and linked the source code.

But at runtime, `DWORD` alignment exception occurrs. I found that on ARM build, it seems that `ARMOPT_BITIO` should be declared for properly aligned read & write. But with `ARMOPT_BITIO`, some IO functions are missing, e. g. `peekBits`, `getBits`, `flushToByte`, `flushBits`.

I copied x86 version of these functions (`peekBit16`, `flushBit16`, etc), but no luck, it does not work (I've got a stack overflow error).

I can't debug the complex HD Photo source files. Please let me know where can I find the missing ARM code.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience of porting some Microsoft code to ARM Linux, I do not think there is an easy way around it, unless someone has ported it already. You'll have to dive into this sort of low-level debugging.

Bugs I encountered were mainly related to unaligned access, and missing platform API calls. Also incorrect preprocessor checks resulted in code thinking it's running on big-endian platform.

The method I found useful to debug in such scenario is to build the code for the target platform *and* for the platform where it's known to work, *and debug/trace these builds in parallel* using a number of use cases. This will catch the most severe bugs.